# On browser close, JavaScript does not always call a custom server side method (Asp.Net/C#)

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

On browser close event, I am trying to call a server side method from JavaScript, to make some database table changes. I am doing this in the “onbeforeunload” event in JavaScript.

Most of the time, it is successfully calling the server side code and implementing the expected database table changes**. **But sometimes, the Server side event does not get invoked.****

Does anyone have any experience with a similar requirement OR would be able to provide us any suggestions on how we can make sure that the Server side event gets invoked always without fail?

Comment: That's because calling async functions on beforeunload is at best unreliable as the browser will often close the window before the call was sent.

Comment: Adding to what @adeneo said, you can show a progress bar or something and make a syncronous ajax call on onbeforeunload to make the server side changes

Answer (score 0):

Aha, we had one of those problems a while back, where we absolutely needed to give our server notification that the window has closed. We noticed that only Firefox would obey requests made inside `onbeforeunload`. Finally, the solution is as follows:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "...",
        data: "(what you want to send)",
        async: false                             // THIS
    });
});
```

What's more peculiar is that neither `window.onunload` nor `window.onbeforeunload` worked for us; not back then at least.